# Only displaying Legend for elements present inside another polygon?

Tags: qgis, legend

I am building a map of a particular region and imported some data layers with lots of attributes because it's got info on the entire country. Many of these attributes aren't present in the region I want to show the legend of: How could I simplify the legend, or "purge" it, so it's only relevant to the area inside the highlighted/red outline polygon in this picture?
[image: Lots of possible values which bloat my legend when printing]

Comment: What we see here is the QGIS main window? Then in fact, it's not a legend, but the layers panel, right?

Comment: Sorry yes, this is the QGIS main screen, not the printing layout editor.

Answer (score 2):

### Filter style visible in the map canva

The layer tree have an option that could be use to filter attribute use in your canvas.

Just click in this icon : [image]

As the canva is larger than your target region there migth be styles that doesn't exist in your target region. If it is not ok for you use the method below.

### Filter style visible in a target region.

There is no direct button to do so you will have to do sevral steps :

1. Use the tool spatial join to give your landcover layer one of the attribute you have in your region layer.
2. Duplicate the layer you have produced and set one layer filter to see only your target region (the filter will be based on the attribute you just joined) and the other layer to be the opposite.
3. Click in the button image above and expand only the layer you have filtered only your target region.

Hope it will answer your question.